# Using CI for Bitbucket repository - do I need to have node_modules inside my root folder?

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I am trying to Buddy.works using their CI to upload my themes in in test, staging and production mode.

I have noticed when the files are compiled using Webpack that it is also uploading node_modules to the root folder.

It is taking an age to upload everything. Do I really need those files if the build is finished within Webpack?

Normally working on my project locally all node_modules have to be installed in order to use them. Do I need to include the node_modules in the cloud also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard is to not push `node_modules` to the SCM(Git, SVN, Mercurial) because they take a lot of space. That's why we have `package.json`. So on a CI/CD tool like Jenkins, Circle CI or Travis you would specify the build to run `npm install --production` and it would take care of creating and downloading the necessary dependencies to the `node_modules` folder.

This makes the build faster too as the first step would be something like,

```
git clone <repo_url>
```

If you had pushed your `node_modules` folder it would take longer to clone due to the extra size.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Figured out node_modules should not be in the root folder. If i install vendors (JS libraries) on Webpack build in production or development mode the CI will just handle everything without even having it to upload the node_modules folder to the root. Btw i have tried working with Bitbucket Pipeline but didn't like it so much. Which one is free and do you suggest for React Apps and WordPress websites mostly?

Comment: @Galanthus I love Circle CI. Best for hosted CI/CD. Check it out, https://circleci.com/

Comment: It is so damn.. expensive. How about free plans?

Comment: @Galanthus It's free with a few limitations but it's more than sufficient for testing. https://circleci.com/pricing/

Comment: Thank you for the advice on CI. Don't know what was i thinking that node_modules have to be in the root FTP folder. Accepted answer i will try CircleCI. Thanks!